# Handling error in function, notify then skip

Tags: r, function, loops, error-handling

I am having trouble process a function that can both output regression summary to csv files, and process regression analysis. So the code looks like this:

I have three predicting variables: 
age1 (continuous), gender1 (categorical 0/1), FLUSHOT(categorical  0/1)

In the file, the first 100 columns are response variables (all categorical 0/1) I want to test.

The goal is to do regression analysis with each of the response variables(1:100), and only output p-value, OR, and CI.

So the code I have is something looks like this:

```
fun1<-function(x){
  res<-c(paste(as.character(summary(x)$call),collapse = " "),
         summary(x)$coefficients[4,4],
         exp(coef(x))[4],
         exp(confint(x))[4,1:2],"\n")

  names(res)<-c("call","p-value","OR","LCI","UCI","")
  return(res)}


res2=NULL
lms=list()
for(i in 1:100)
{
  lms[[i]]=glm(A[,i]~age1+gender1+as.factor(FLUSHOT),family="binomial",data=A)               
  res2<-rbind(res2,fun1(lms[[i]]))
}
write.csv(res2,"A_attempt1.csv",row.names=F)
```

If for example, we have sufficient sample size in each categories, or if the marginal frequency looks like this:

```
table(variable1,FLUESHOT)
   0    1
0  15   3
1  11   19
```

This code works well, but if we have something like:

```
 table(variable15,FLUESHOT)
       0    1
    0  15   0
    1  11   19
```

The code run into a error, report, and stops.

I tried multiple ways of using `try()` and `tryCatch()`, but didn't seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

What error message do you see?  You can try using lrm from the rms package to estimate the logistic regression model.  And texreg to output it to csv.

Comment: Kat, thank you for replying. The error code I got is like this.   

Error in approx(sp$y, sp$x, xout = cutoff) :
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
 
Is there any possible ways to bypass this error?

Comment: Hi Yayi, this means that your data are sometimes completely missing (or only have one observation).  Also, try-catch will only keep you from finding the errors in the data that you need to remove.  I'd suggest that you loop through the data and check that it's okay for each attempted model (e.g. cross-tabulate the DV and a feature).

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i did, clean it before running, and that works. Thank you very much.   However I'm still hopping there would be a way to just output error, and move on without stopping the whole process. Hopefully I'll figure it out.